# How to add all text in a column into one cell in Snowflake

Tags: sql, group-by, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have data as follows:

```
ID   tags
001  apple, banana
001  NA
002  berry, blue, banana
003  melon, apple, grape
002  grape
001  apple, banana
001  grape
```

All I would like to do is make a new table which gathers all text into one cell as follows:

```
ID   tag_full
001  apple, banana, apple, banana, grape
002  berry, blue, banana, grape
003  melon, apple, grape
```

So all values of tags are in one cell for each ID. Order does not matter, but they must be separated by commas.

Comment: This  is like the 6th question I've seen combinging rows of data into one row.  today.  Very weird.  Note: this is better suited for the UI.  How "BIG" Can  this list get?  there's an upper limit to the number of characters so one must be ready to handel that potential.  De-normalizing data like this is painful to use later where as multiple /row/column is better stuited.  So maybe this is fine, maybe not but consider the impacts.

Comment: Yeah man so basically I need all tags for each user. Then in Python i will count how many times each tag appeared for each user. So new vars like, apple_count, banana_count, etc.

Comment: a string can have max size of ~16MB (`varchar(16777216)`) so for most situations you will be fine..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about this :

```
select id , listagg(tags , ',') as tag_full
from tablename 
where tags <> 'NA'
group by id
```

Comment: Close, but I need repeat instances of tags, so no distinct

Comment: So just needs to remove the `distinct` from the `listagg(distinct..)` and it would work right?

Answer (score 2):

so the same answer as eshirvana:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    listagg(tags, ',') as full_tags
FROM VALUES 
    (001,  'apple, banana'),
    (001, 'NA'),
    (002,  'berry, blue, banana'),
    (003,  'melon, apple, grape'),
    (002,  'grape'),
    (001,  'apple, banana'),
    (001,  'grape')
    v(id, tags)
WHERE tags != 'NA'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

but it seems rather gross to aggregate in SQL and the count the data in python, when it can be done directly in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    array_agg(object_construct(tag, tag_count)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tag_count desc) as full_tags
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id
        ,trim(t.value) as tag
        ,count(*) as tag_count
    FROM VALUES 
        (001,  'apple, banana'),
        (001, 'NA'),
        (002,  'berry, blue, banana'),
        (003,  'melon, apple, grape'),
        (002,  'grape'),
        (001,  'apple, banana'),
        (001,  'grape')
        v(id, tags) 
        ,table(split_to_table(tags, ',')) as t
    WHERE tags != 'NA'
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

| ID | FULL_TAGS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ { "apple": 2 }, { "banana": 2 }, { "grape": 1 } ] |
| 2 | [ { "berry": 1 }, { "blue": 1 }, { "banana": 1 }, { "grape": 1 } ] |
| 3 | [ { "melon": 1 }, { "grape": 1 }, { "apple": 1 } ] |

Comment: I'm following what you are doing, but the thing is. I need to use this data for a ML model, where each tag group is a variable. If FULL_TAGS ends up the way you show, how could I break this out to be columns? This would HAVE to be in python, like Apple column, banana column , etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243451/using-pandas-to-create-new-variables-from-a-comma-separated-column/71243627#71243627

Comment: my output is a sparse output, where the linked output is a dense representation. They are not too hard to flip between, in SQL that is a PIVOT command, BUT if you know how to do the work in Python, and not is SQL use the tools you know.